# $c^n$ vs $n^{\log n}$ : which one grows faster? c is a constant

Tags: limits

So i always thought $n^{\log n}$ should be bigger, but i watched a video and the guy said $n^{\log n}$ will be smaller than $c^n$, i don't get it, how?

also is this true for ANY $c > 1$?

$n > 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n^{\ln n} = e^{(\ln n)^2}$
and 
$(\ln n)^2 < n$

Comment: But you need to compare $(\ln n)^2$ and $(\ln c) n$.

Answer (score 0):

Take logs of each to compare

$$n\ln c <> (\ln n)^2.$$

The left side is a straight line with positive slope.  The right side is 
concave down.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true. To see it, just take the definition of $n^{\log n}$:
$$n^{\log n}=\mathrm e^{\log n\log n}=\mathrm e^{\log^2 n}, \enspace\text{whereas }\quad c^n=\mathrm e^{n\log c},$$
and it is known from high-school that $\log^2n=o(n)$, so that the  ratio
$$\frac{n^{\log n}}{n^c}=\mathrm e^{\log^2 n-n\log c} \longrightarrow\begin{cases}0&\text{if } c>1,\\+\infty&\text{if } c\le1.\end{cases}$$